# Where is the first code run on Zircon (Fuchsia) kernel on this start.S file?

Tags: assembly, fuchsia

I'm reading the start.S assembly code for the Zircon Kernel (Fuchsia OS):

https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/master/zircon/kernel/arch/arm64/start.S

There's this line:

```
.text
FUNCTION(_start)
```

I think this is the first thing ever that get executed on the kernel. However, for it to be true, `_start` should be global. I couldn't determine if it is or not.

There's this other line:

```
// This symbol is used by image.S
.global IMAGE_ELF_ENTRY
IMAGE_ELF_ENTRY = _start
```

that suggests something like it.

What is `FUNCTION` on `FUNCTION(_start)`? I tried searching for "assembly FUNCTION macro" but found nothing related to this.

It looks like this is the first code run, but I could not determine where it branches to real kernel code (C++ code) so I'm in doubt.

Comment: [`FUNCTION` is an assembly directive for marking the start of a function.](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361290014133.htm) IN that link it is said it is used for DWARF symbols, I assume it also makes the symbol globally visible. Note that I searched "arm assembly FUNCTION", always include the architecture in your queries ;) The jump to the kernel should be around [here](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/master/zircon/kernel/arch/arm64/start.S#299) but I'm not used to ARM. That just looks like an entry-point and `bl .` looks like an infinite fallback loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of these macros can be found in [`//zircon/kernel/include/asm.h`](https://cs.opensource.google/fuchsia/fuchsia/+/master:zircon/kernel/include/asm.h;l=24;drc=ee22ed56132d36ae95f35c5b53c0ce5d02a5a59c), it's basically a wrapper that adds all the required annotations, including [CFI directives](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2017/01/18/cfi.html).

So `FUNCTION(_start)` would expand to:

```
.global _start;
.hidden _start;
.type _start,STT_FUNC;
_start:
  .cfi_startproc
```

The branching to C++ code happens on the [`bl lk_main`](https://cs.opensource.google/fuchsia/fuchsia/+/master:zircon/kernel/arch/arm64/start.S;l=299;drc=2757e6f0f7304160ea38d9126361d6de0f79345f) instruction.